# Possible to vectorize this array operation in python?

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

Beginner in Python here, I have a hard time wrapping my head around vectorizing my 'for' loops.
I have a 2D numpy array, containing only two values -1 and 1. For each column and row I want to do the following operation: set all -1 values encountered before the first time a 1 is encountered to 0.
Can this be vectorized? Even without crashing if there's no 1 in a row/column and thus the whole row/column is to be set to 0?

Comment: Can you give some sample input and output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one vectorized approach -

```
mask = a==1
a[~np.maximum.accumulate(mask,axis=0)] = 0
a[~np.maximum.accumulate(mask,axis=1)] = 0
```

Sample run -

```
In [39]: a
Out[39]: 
array([[ 1, -1,  1, -1, -1],
       [ 1,  1, -1,  1, -1],
       [-1,  1, -1,  1, -1],
       [ 1, -1, -1, -1, -1]])

In [40]: mask = a==1

In [41]: a[~np.maximum.accumulate(mask,axis=0)] = 0

In [42]: a[~np.maximum.accumulate(mask,axis=1)] = 0

In [43]: a
Out[43]: 
array([[ 1,  0,  1,  0,  0],
       [ 1,  1, -1,  1,  0],
       [ 0,  1, -1,  1,  0],
       [ 1, -1, -1, -1,  0]])
```